# How to use declared variable to create a json element

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a stored procedure, in this, I have declared a variable which holds a value from a select function. I need to use this value to create a json element, but it throws an exception

```
function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, character varying, boolean) does not exist
```

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test ( ) RETURNS 
INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
intent varchar;
BEGIN  

select id into intent from customer;
UPDATE orders
SET data = jsonb_set(
data, 
'{Items}',      -- the array in which we operate
to_jsonb(
(WITH ar AS(
  WITH temp AS(
    SELECT data->'Items' AS items   -- the array in which we operate
    FROM orders
    WHERE id = 1    -- the filtered order we are updating
  )
  SELECT jsonb_set(
    jsonb_array_elements(items),
    '{Quantity}',   -- the new field we are adding
    intent,          -- this is where i need to replace the variable
    true)
  FROM temp)
 SELECT (array_agg(ar.jsonb_set))
 FROM ar)),
 false)
  WHERE id = 1;
return 0;

EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN

return 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Copying the snippet where I need to replace the variable:

```
SELECT jsonb_set(
    jsonb_array_elements(items),
    '{Quantity}',   -- the new field we are adding
    intent,          -- this is where i need to replace the variable
    true)
```

Comment: my postgres version is9.6.11

Comment: if i replace a string in place of variable intent it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly cast `intent` to `jsonb` using `CAST(intent AS jsonb)` or `intent::jsonb`.

The reason it works with a string literal is that such literals are of the (internal) type `unknown` which can be transformed to most other types, but there is no implicit cast between `character varying` and `jsonb`, so you have to use an explicit one.